# Вопрос по frontend

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Коллеги, подскажите, как лучше сверстать этот  border всего лендинга на макете.
Не понимаю, что делать, там еще и узор на border.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

`border-image` - используется для отображения рисованной рамки вокруг элемента.

Пример:

```
    border-image: url(images/bg-image.png) 30 round round;
```

где 
`url` - путь к изображению; 
    `30` - толщина границы;
    `round` - повторяет рисунок и масштабирует его так, чтобы на стороне элемента оказалось целое число изображений.

[Ссылка на док.](https://webref.ru/css/border-image)

**Вариант 2:**

Использовать несколько фоновых картинок.

Например:

```
background: 
     url(images/block-1.png) Npx Npx no-repeat,
     url(images/block-2.png) Npx N% no-repeat, 
     url(images/block-3.png) Npx N% repeat-y;
```

[Ссылка на док.1](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/dva-fona-i-bolshe)
[Ссылка на док.2](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-dva-fona-k-odnomu-elementu-cherez-css3)

Comment: А можно сделать как-то так только с border.---
background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center;---
т.е. чтобы я мог изменять цвет border и картинку поверх цветного border?